PaperTrail has_paper_trail must be called only once
I am using paper_trail in my Rails application to track some changes in ActionText::RichText fields like this:
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_text_rich_text) do
  ActionText::RichText.class_eval do
    has_paper_trail
  end
end

After updating to the lastest version of paper_trail I found that a gem I use also is using that strategy to track ActionText::RichText fields and I can't start my application without a PaperTrail error being thrown saying that I can't call has_paper_trail multiple times. Is there a way around this? Can I somehow override any other calls to has_paper_trail?

I too am facing the same issue after update did you fix it?

It's because of this - https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/pull/1479
I still don't know how to fix this. Will update once I find the solution

Unfortunately I had to make the papertrail call in the gem configurable. I fortunately was able to get the change incorporated in the gem but if I hadn't been able to do that I still don't know of a way to fix this.
